# Text over flipped image CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been selflearning a bit about Jscript and CSS playing with the code of this card memory game:
https://marina-ferreira.github.io/projects/js/memory-game/

Which I have in codeopen here:
https://codepen.io/jaimesoza/pen/xxwJBde

I would like to add some text (the name of the card) only to the flipped version, for obvious reasons. I've seen some examples which do that, but I have not been able to apply them to this current CSS, as I am a total noob in these matters. Every time I try something similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp) I end up messing everything.

```
CSS
    .bottom-right {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 16px;
    }

HTML

  <img src="Dog.jpg" alt="Dog" style="width:100%;">
   <div class="bottom-right">Dog</div>
```

I think it is quite simple for somebody with experience with css, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Some few changes of your code you will get your desire output.

First put your all **class="front-face"** images in a div like shown below.

```
<div class="front-face" >
<img style = "width: 100%; height:100%; "src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7f/24/d8/7f24d81c34fc9ed92e5d1a71c1969d36.png" alt="Dog"/>
        <div class="bottom-right">Dog</div>
       </div>
```

Then changes following style sheets as follows.

```
.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 23px; // This value is only changed
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1C7CCC;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then add you new class CSS in style sheet

```
.bottom-right {
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      bottom: 3px;
      color: white;
      left:60px
    }
```

You will get something like this [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, it is not working for me, maybe I am doing something wrong: I get the pictures full-sized, and not wrapped inside the "memorycard":
https://i.imgur.com/8z1ASZv.jpg

https://codepen.io/jaimesoza/pen/xxwJBde

Do you know what might be happening?

Comment: Sorry! i go through your updated code and you already use it. Just a little problem i found again that you didn't use any inline style in img tag as i mentioned above. Please use it as i mentioned ( style = "width: 100%; height:100%; " ) in img tag. Have a good day brother.

````

<div class="front-face" >
<img style = "width: 100%; height:100%; "src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7f/24/d8/7f24d81c34fc9ed92e5d1a71c1969d36.png" alt="Dog"/>
        <div class="bottom-right">Dog</div>
       </div>

````

Comment: Excellent! That made the trick! Thanks, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you :)